# Azure functions blob trigger - Use same receipts for different host names and new versions of the function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I am using azure functions with the blob trigger and with the runtime 2.x. After the function being executed the runtime adds blob receipt into the location below (azure-webjob-hosts>blobreceipt>)
[image: receipt path]

Is there any way to make runtime to use the same hostnameid in the path (in this case it's 8a76f42c1c01-2137340777)? Because if run function locally or publish new version of the code it would use different host identifier (like macbook-id).

The main problem is when I run `func azure functionapp publish` it will requeue all the existing blobs with new version of the code even when the new version has the same func name because it will use different host/func identifier to check for receipts.

I know that in runtime v1 you could add `id` into host.json. I dont see such option in runtime v2.

Edit:

Another thing. Just this morning I found out that my function run over all the blobs again. When I looked into blobreceipts I see that the hostid has changed and there are new bunch of receipts for the new host id. Host Id has changed even though I didnt do any deployments. How is that possible? I have also reported the bug on coretools about hostid getting changed on publish. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1012

App name is `altamente-prod-svc-shopify-background`. But the host id is `d7031c9b43fc-2137340777`. I have removed all receipts to do more tests for now but you can see in logs that the func was initiated again this morning by itself over all my 7 blobs. There is just one function for now (and also WarmUp func which appeared automatically). I have created the linux func app via Azure portal with no functions and then just did publish with core tools from my mac.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround now in the [Azure Functions bug report](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1012) that you linked to.  Basically, set `AzureFunctionsWebHost:hostid` in the App settings to some explicit value.  I'm using a self-hosted functions runtime and [Kubernetes doesn't allow colons in environment variables](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53201), so I used the work-around of setting `AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostid` instead, which also works.